# Tensorflow The two structures don't have the same nested structure in while_loop although loop_vars and body arguments are the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop, typeerror

I'm trying to implement contrastive divergence in tensorflow, but I'm getting this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
def gibbs_step(self, v_act, v_prob, v_mf, h_act, h_prob, h_mf):
    h_mf = tf.matmul(v_act, self.w) + self.hidden_bias
    h_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(h_mf)
    h_act = self.hidden_activation(h_mf, h_prob)

    v_mf = tf.matmul(h_act, tf.transpose(self.w)) + self.visible_bias
    v_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(v_mf)
    v_act = self.visible_activation(v_mf, v_prob)
    return [v_act, v_prob, v_mf, h_act, h_prob, h_mf]

def contrastive_divergence(self, x):
    v_act = tf.identity(x)#(tf.zeros([self.n_visibles]), dtype=tf.float32)
    v_prob = tf.zeros_like(x)
    v_mf = tf.zeros_like(x)
    h_act = tf.zeros_like(self.h_mf)
    h_prob = tf.zeros_like(self.h_mf)
    h_mf = tf.zeros_like(self.h_mf)

    def always_true(*kwargs):
        return True

    cond = always_true
    loop_vars = [v_act, v_prob, v_mf, h_act, h_prob, h_mf]

    return tf.while_loop(cond, self.gibbs_step, loop_vars, maximum_iterations = self.k)
```

From the errorlog I can see that the dimensions are correct, however, what in the error log is called "second structure" is a tuple instead of a list. I guess this is what is causing the error but itis not clear for me where it comes from, `gibbs_step` is returning a list and `loop_vars` is also a list.

```
TypeError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=list str=[<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, [<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_2:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_3:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_4:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_5:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_6:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>]]

Second structure: type=list str=[<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/add:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, (<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/random_normal_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Sigmoid_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/add_2:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Relu:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/add_1:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>)]

More specifically: The two namedtuples don't have the same sequence type. First structure type=list str=[<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_2:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_3:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_4:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_5:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Identity_6:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>] has type list, while second structure type=tuple str=(<tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/random_normal_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Sigmoid_1:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/add_2:0' shape=(?, 400) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Relu:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'contrastive_divergence/while/add_1:0' shape=(?, 150) dtype=float32>) has type tuple
```

Any help on this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide reproducible example I could help you. There are a lot of things you are doing incorrectly in your code, but without having reproducible code it is really hard to help. It least provide the exact shapes of `x`, `self.h_mf` , self.k, etc

Comment: Sure, thanks @Vlad. `x` would be a tensor of shape `[None, 400]` and `self.h_mf` has shape `[None, 150]`. What things would you say are incorrect?

Comment: And you want to iterate over the first dimension (i.e. `None`), right?

Comment: I want to iterate `self.k` times. Not sure what you mean by first dimension. First dimension is batchsize

Comment: Each tensor has dimension that starts with (`None`, ...) where `None` is a batch size. You want to iterate over the dimension of number of samples (over each sample in a batch), OR, you want to apply the same operation multiple times one the same data?

Comment: What I want to do is perform `gibbs_step()` over my `loop_vars`. And do it `self.k` times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192003/discussion-between-vlad-and-isaac).